# Can I use a union using set notation and interval notation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can i represent the union of something with set and interval notation?

for example,

{$3, 8$} $\cup\space [1, 5]$.

Would this be allowed? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes you absolutely can.

Comment: Yes. No problem about that.

Comment: $\{3,8\}$ is a set.  $[1,5]$ is a set.  You can union any two sets, regardless.  The fact that your two sets in question happen to be written with different notation does not change this fact.

Comment: Yes and since $3\in[1,5]$ you can write it as {$8$}$\cup[1,5]$.

Comment: Did you ask this with a specific use case? For example, if it's a random variable's support, it's probability density can be defined with Dirac Delta terms, plus a function of support $[1, \, 5]$.

Answer (score 0):

As a many commentors have pointed out: Yes, you certainly can. In your case $[1,5]$ already contains $\{3\}$, so you can simplify by writing it as $\{8\} \cup [1,5]$.
.
.